# Creating materialized view from ArcSDE layer

Tags: enterprise-geodatabase, oracle-dbms, arccatalog

In the past I've used materialized views in Oracle to replicate non-spatial data from one database to another. I'd like to do the same thing with an ArcSDE feature class, but I'm wondering how that will work at the ArcSDE level. I've tried creating the view with a simple `CREATE MATERIALIZED VIEW` statement (no ArcSDE involved) and then registering it with the geodatabase, but I can't get the data to display in ArcMap.

In general I would prefer to create the table within ArcSDE (i.e. in ArcCatalog) and then create the materialized view on top of that. I know there's a syntax for creating views [ON PREBUILT TABLE](http://www.dba-oracle.com/t_materialized_views_on_prebuilt_table.htm), but I'm getting an error `ORA-32304: materialized views with user-defined types cannot use prebuilt table`. I'm guessing that's in reference to the geometry column which is ST_GEOMETRY. Does anyone know of a better way to make a materialized view from a feature class?

Comment: You may be required to use SDO_GEOMETRY storage to utilize materialized views for spatial data transfer, but even then you might hit limitations.  Oracle isn't fond of remote server spatial queries so you might be best off making a WKT CLOB of the geometry for transmission.